# Do all virtual devices in the Android Studio emulator require HAXM?

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device, haxm

I am attempting to run an apk file on a work computer, but I can't install HAXM without admin permissions. Can earlier system images run without it?

Answer (score 0):

Intel HAXM just adds hardware capabilities to speed up the emulation.

You can work without Haxm.
Also, you can use other emulators like LDplayer.

I would suggest using an actual physical device for development.
It runs much faster and doesn't bog your pc down.